# Invalid specialized parameter in method lambda list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write a simple coin flip program in Common Lisp. This is the code I have

```
(defun yn
 (let ht (random 1)
  (if (eq ht 1)
   (princ heads)
   (princ tails))
 )
)
```

It seems simple enough, but I keep getting the error:

```
"Invalid specialized parameter in method lambda list (LET HT (RANDOM 1) (IF (EQ HT 1) (PRINC HEADS) (PRINC TAILS))): (IF (EQ HT 1) (PRINC HEADS) (PRINC TAILS))"
      )
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Here you can download a great introductory book: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `defun` without parameters, there should be an empty parameter list, like the following:

```
(defun yn ()
  (let ((ht (random 2)))
    (if (eq ht 1)
        (princ heads)
        (princ tails))))
```

Comment: The `let` syntax is wrong too, so much so that it doesn't run, and it should signal an error when compiling.

Comment: @Paulo: Thanks, I didn't notice that part. I also incorporated what suggested by @Vatine, i.e. `(random 2)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `defun` is malformed (lacking an empty parameter list).
Your `let` is malformed (the general structure is `(let (<bind-spec>...) <body>)`, where the binding is either a symbol (initially bound to `nil`) or a `(<symbol> <value>)` list.

Both `heads` and `tails` seem to be unbound, it's not clear if you mean the literal symbols or are using dynamically-scoped variables.

Your call to `random` probably doesn't do what you want, the HyperSpec says "Returns a pseudo-random number that is a non-negative number less than limit and of the same type as limit. ", so `(random 1)` can only return 0.

Below is a cleaned-up version that addresses all of these points, assuming you're after having the literal symbols `heads` and `tails` printed.

```
(defun yn ()
  (let ((ht (random 2)))
    (if (eq ht 1)
      (princ 'heads)
      (princ 'tails)))
```

Comment: The let syntax in the answer is still wrong.  You're defining a variable `ht` initialized with `nil` and a variable `random` initialized with 2.